# Unity multiplayer global variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have `Player(NetworkBehaviour)` script attached to player prefab which spawn when client join and `Global(MonoBehaviour)` script which is inside scene

In Global script i have this:

```
class Global : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int gloablInteger;

    void Start()
    {
         globalInteger = 0;
    }
}
```

In Player Script i have this:

```
class Player : Networkbehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Global.globalInteger++;
    }
}
```

I set up in update function to `Debug.Log(globalInteger)` and it prints `0`, then first client(host) join and it prints `1`, then second client joins and it still prints `1` instead of `2`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime a client joins it resets globalInteger to 0 in Start() function.

Comment: Why? That global scrip is attatched to empty fameobject in scene and it stays there

Comment: When client loads the scene he runs Start() on every MonoBehaviour locally
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: I am new to multiplayer so didn't know. I will try it and tell you what happened

Comment: If you are using UNet and want to synchronize one value across the clients use SyncVar https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html

Comment: But also there is one problem, i need to sync custom class. In question i set up simple environment but in my code it is custom class and by documents it can sync only simple types

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to sync anything other than simple types

Comment: Well i will use other way then. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

This is my Script

**clientS**

```
void Start () 
{
    globalS.g++;
    Debug.Log(globalS.g); //1,2,3,4,5
}
```

**globalS**

```
public static int g = 0;
```

I think you may **reset** the value **globalInteger**, or did not call **Global.globalInteger++** in right way, note each GameObject Start function only call once in runtime.

Comment: I know that but for some reason is not working. If i have global monobehaviour script and with client1 I change something to it, will client2 see changes?